# Transform any data to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, type-conversion

I am new in this community.

I am working in a project that i can not finish, unfortunately. After hours of looking for something to solve my issue, my last chance is to ask here:

Let's say i have a string or data like this:

```
{"PSInstall":false,"DeviceID":"","RootBlock":false,"MobileData":false,"ExpireDate":1669794843523,"Message":"Follow me on telegram\nhttps:\/\/t.me\/channel\nFollow me on YouTube\nhttps:\/\/youtube.com\/channel\/channel","Payload":"www.example.com","SSLProxy":"","isDirect":false,"isSSL":true,"isSSLProxy":false,"isWS":true,"isDNS":false,"Server":""}
```

Although this one looks like a JSON and can be translated and pretty print in JSON format, like:

```
{
  example: value,
  example2, value
}
```

Sometimes it is not a string that can't be converted to JSON due to missing a character or something. So, i am looking for a way, if it is possible, to extract any key and data from a given string, separated by ":", and make a JSON.

In others words, i am trying to make a tool (offline) like this website:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

Any data you put there that looks similar to a dict (or JSON) will be fixed and pretty printed in JSON format.
This website in particular has an API, but it can't be accessed from a Python Script.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Max

I tried this, which works in some cases (but not all the cases):

```
import json, sys, os
from shutil import which

def clear():
  if os.name == 'nt':
    os.system('cls')
  else:
    os.system('clear')

clear()
data = input('Enter JSON data:\n')
print('\n\n')
#data = json.loads(data)
#result = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
clear()
#print(result)
print('\n')

while True:
  try:
    data = json.loads(data)
    break
  except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
    print("Ok, error")
    if e.args[0].startswith("Expecting ',' delimiter:"):
      data = ','.join((data[:e.pos], data[e.pos:]))
    elif e.args[0].startswith("Expecting ':' delimiter:"):
      data = ':'.join((data[:e.pos], data[e.pos:]))
      sys.exit()
    else:
      print(e)
      break

result = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(result, '\n')
```

Comment: I tried that site. If I enter something that isn't valid JSON, it reports a bunch of errors.

Comment: It's hard to write something that will work in all cases. The whole reason we have standards like JSON is because anything else will have ambiguities.

Comment: First convert the file to Python Dictionary before converting it to JSON. You can use ast.literal.eval or eval to convert it to dictionary

Comment: Thank you to both of you for the answer (and thank you Mr Barmar for the corrections on the post).

I will try that @MaxwellD.Dorliea I will try to conver them in dict at least and show the result as "Key: Value" as items, for example.